# Unrelated "terror bombing"?

Tags: stellaris

I'm currently in a messy war spree and to achieve my goals, I employ limited (medium) bombardment. Thing is, my POPs at other planets get a load of happiness debuffs called "Terror Bombing". The Stellaris Wiki explicitly states that POPs get this effect when under bombardment, but I'm getting tremendous amount of these on a planet which was never a subject to a war, trading or independence (uplifted world). Why am I getting it, and how to remove these effects? Right now, it heavily impedes my Energy Credit rate.

Comment: >The pops happiness modifier Pacifist.png pacifist pops receive -5% happiness and all Fanatic Pacifist.png fanatic pacifist pops received -10% happiness for 3600 days. Source:http://www.stellariswiki.com/Orbital_bombardment Could have something to do with it, not sure, don't have the game..

Comment: I've seen this too, on a planet that 100% sure was not bombed by the enemy. My best guess was that I was bombing an enemy planet that had no defenses left, so bombing was not doing anything - which might be called "bombing for the terror effect only." (It's only a guess; If someone has proof, please turn that into an answer)

Answer (score 3):

I found this information on the [Stellaris reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Stellaris/comments/4j2xvw/what_is_terror_bombing/) which got it from the wiki. (For some reason I cannot load the wiki myself)

When you are performing orbital bombardment successfully killing a POP on that planet can trigger the Terror Bombing modifier if your empire is not militaristic or fanatic militaristic. This lowers your happiness by 5% if your empire is pacifist or 10% if you are fanatic pacifist on planets in your empire. The only way to get rid of this debuff is to stop killing POPs through orbital bombardment for around 3,600 days.